# Try to show base64 image (Razor)

Tags: string, image, asp.net-core, razor, base64

I want to set base64 string(image) to img html tag as src like blow in razor page:

```
string qoute_image =String.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}",table1.Rows[0][1].ToString());
```

i assign variable to img tag:

```
<img src="@qoute_image"  style="width:100px;height:100px;align-content:center;">
```

[qoute_image value screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC19d.png)

but when trace via visual studio and check value of qoute_image variable at runtime, it's correct, and i test the base64 string of value of qoute_image variable with online base64 to image convertor, and it works properly..
[online convertor base64 to image- screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fhjW.png)

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

but when use inspect element from google chrome, and check value of src="" option from  tag, the base64 string was changed ... and value of "qoute_image" variable is unequal and not the same as the value of  src value.

and no result:
[different value of img tag - error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DF0j.png)

Comment: As a diagnostic step, try replacing your dynamic `qoute_image` variable with a static base64 string (the same one you tested with the online converter) directly in the Razor page. If this works as expected, the issue might lie in how the variable `qoute_image` is being set or manipulated before it reaches the `<img>` tag.

Comment: From myside, it can display the image correctly by using static string.  Sometimes, Razor might HTML encode your string in ways you don't expect, which could alter the appearance of the base64 string when inspected in the browser. To prevent HTML encoding, you can try to use `Html.Raw()`: `<img src="@Html.Raw(qoute_image)" style="width:100px;height:100px;align-content:center;">`

Comment: thank you @Rena for devoting your time to answering my questions... you are right.. please write your comment as an answer, so i can accept it for your stackoverflow rank..

Comment: Hi @test test, I convert the comment to answer now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooting:

As a diagnostic step, try replacing your dynamic `qoute_image` variable with a static base64 string (the same one you tested with the online converter) directly in the Razor page. If this works as expected, the issue might lie in how the variable `qoute_image` is being set or manipulated before it reaches the `<img>` tag.

Solution:

Sometimes, Razor might HTML encode your string in ways you don't expect, which could alter the appearance of the base64 string when inspected in the browser. To prevent HTML encoding, you can try to use `Html.Raw()`:

```
<img src="@Html.Raw(qoute_image)" style="width:100px;height:100px;align-content:center;">
```